# Do I have to use a Union Find data structure when implementing Kruskal's algoithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph

From what I've read about Kruskal's algorithm, it seems like we have to use a union find data structure. But why can't I just use an array of booleans which indicate whether a particular vertex has been added to the MST and just check that both vertices of an edge are have not been added to the MST instead? I.e. something like this (this is Java-like but is pseudocode-ish so it probably won't compile):

```
public Queue<Edge> getMST(Graph graph) {
  boolean[] visited = new boolean[graph.numVertices()];
  PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
  Queue<Edge> mstPath = new Queue<>();
  pq.addAll(graph.edges());
  while(mstPath.size() < graph.numVertices() - 1 && pq.isNotEmpty()) {
    Edge curr = pq.getMin();
    if (visited[curr.to] && visited[curr.from]) continue; // ignore because both vertices of this edge are in MST
    mstPath.add(curr);
    visited[curr.to] = true;
    visited[curr.from] = true;
  }
  return mstPath;
}
```

So why should I use a Union Find data structure? Won't the above work and be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Kruskal's algorithm works is that you start with a bunch of disconnected vertices and you add edges one at a time until you have a spanning tree that connects all the vertices. If at each step you add the cheapest possible edge, the final spanning tree will have minimum cost.

So what you have do do at each step is find the cheapest edge that you can add without forming a cycle. To do this, you need to have a quick way of determining if a pair of vertices is already connected. If they are already connected, adding an edge between them will introduce a cycle. If they are not connected, you  can add the edge, which will connect two separate components in the graph.

The naive datastructure for this is to have an array that stores one number for each vertex with each different number corresponding to a different connected component. (Using booleans is not enough - at the start you have one component for each vertex). This array lets you check if two vertices are in the same component in constant time but merging two components is O(N) because you need to update all its elements. The union find datastructure is a bit more clever and can do both of these operations really fast.

---

By the way, perhaps you were confusing Kruskal's algorithm with Prim's algorithm. In Prim's algorithm you keep track of a single tree and in each step you add one vertex not yet in the tree to the tree.

But even then, your proposal wouldn't really work because whenever you add an edge to the tree, one of the vertices is in the tree and the other is not.

Comment: I can't find an example where using the Boolean array doesn't work though. If I treat every vertex that has been added to the MST as a single component (by marking them visited in the Boolean array) then there is no way I could ever add an edge which would create a cycle. The only scenario I can think of where assuming all vertices we have added to the MST are in the same (and only) component is where the graph is disconnected - ie a spanning forest instead of a tree...

Comment: Actually, I've just found a case where using the Boolean array will go wrong, thanks.

Comment: I do think this technique works for Prim's algorithm though, what makes you think it doesn't? You're only ever building one tree with Prim's so you know all visited vertices are in the same tree.

Comment: I misread your if statement. I thought it was doing an `||` instead of an `&&`. So it should work fine for Prim (although of course your if statement will be a bit different because in Prim you loop over vertices instead of looping over edges)

Comment: As for your first comment, Kruskal works by maintaining a spanning forest and addgin edges until the forest becomes a tree. When you start you have a forest with zero edges and each vertex belonging to a separate component and as you add edges you merge components until there is only one left.

Comment: @jcm I had actually the same question. What sort of case would make your Boolean array approach fail? thanks